# Orbits for rotations of shape operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, group-actions

Let $M^n\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ be a submanifold and let $(e_1,\cdots, e_n,e_{n+1},\cdots,e_{n+m})$ be an orthonormal frame field for $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ such that on some open $U\subset M^n$, the $e_i$'s for $1\leq i\leq n$ are tangent to $M^n$ and the $e_\alpha$'s for $n+1\leq \alpha\leq n+m$ are normal.

Then for each $e_\alpha$, there is a shape operator $h^\alpha$ which under a rotation $R\in SO(n)$ on the tangent vectors transforms like $R^T h^\alpha R$. There should also be a transformation on the $h^\alpha$'s by rotation on the normal vectors.

I know in the case of a flat normal bundle that everything can be diagonlized, but what do the orbits of these rotations look like generically?  Or similarly, what are the orbits of $\mathbb{R}^m\otimes S^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ acted on by $SO(m)\times SO(n)$ and are there "nice" representatives of such orbits?